# Tkinter - How to change the color of a label's background if the users input is satisfied using grid

Tags: python, button, tkinter, colors, label

My objective is to change the color of the label to match the color of the frame so that they look nice and sleek. This is my first programming project so help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("250x300-1200-400")

        # input field stored
        self.input_a = tk.StringVar()

        # label
        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Enter Value")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # input field
        input_color_changer = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.input_a)
        input_color_changer.grid(row=0, column=1)

        button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Run", command=self.color_changer)
        button.grid(row=1, column=1)


        self.root.mainloop()


    def color_changer(self):
        input_b = self.input_a.get()

        if input_b == "r":
            self.root["bg"] = "red"
            self.label["bg"] = "red" # <--- code in question
        if input_b == "y":
            self.root["bg"] = "yellow"
        if input_b == "g":
            self.root["bg"] = "green"



Main()
```

Comment: Ok so you have your objective. So tell us what your problem is?

Comment: That said you use `self.label["bg"] = "red"` but do not define `label` as a class attribute. Try changing `label = tk.Label()` to `self.label = tk.Label()`

Comment: You asked this same question about a frame. Why did you need to ask the question twice? Changing the background of a label is the same as changing the background of a label.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `label` as a class attribute. Right now it is just a variable in the `init` method.

To do this add the `self.` prefix.

Here is your code updated a bit to inherit from `Tk()` and use a class attribute for the label.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("250x300-1200-400")
        self.input_a = tk.StringVar()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter Value")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.input_a).grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Button(self, text="Run", command=self.color_changer).grid(row=1, column=1)

    def color_changer(self):
        input_b = self.input_a.get()
        print(input_b)
        if input_b == "r":
            self["bg"] = "red"
            self.label["bg"] = "red"
        if input_b == "y":
            self["bg"] = "yellow"
        if input_b == "g":
            self["bg"] = "green"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]